# curl wsdl soap error - mismatched Actions between sender and receiver

Tags: c, linux, curl, soap, wsdl

I am trying to post the curl based soap request to url using c API's. My libcurl version is curl 7.30.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0 zlib/1.2.5.I am receiving the below error.Also below code i am using to post the request.i am using correct soap action aswell "GetAuthToken", Why this error is happening while posting the request.Thanks in advance.

Error:
The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)

Request:
         123456789

url:
http://x.xx.xx.xxx:20003/HIMS/SecurityService/?wsdl

Sample code:

int main()
{

```
    CURL *curl;

    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    FILE *out_fd = (FILE *) 0;

    char errorbuf[300]="",filename[32]="Response.txt";

    char errmsg[256];

    int Timeout=120;

    int buffer_size = 0;

    char urlbuff[100]="";

    char buff[128] = "http://x.xx.xx.xxx:20003/HIMS/SecurityService/?wsdl";

    memset(urlbuff,0,sizeof(urlbuff));

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    buffer_size = strlen(buffer);
    if(curl)
    {

            out_fd = fopen (filename, "w");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, out_fd);
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8; SOAPAction=GetAuthToken");
            sprintf(urlbuff,"%s",buff);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlbuff);
            Timeout=2000;

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, buffer_size);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, Timeout);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER,errmsg);

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_slist_free_all(headers);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            fclose(out_fd);
            if(CURLE_OK != res)
            {
                    printf("\nerrorbuf:%s:%d\n",errorbuf,res);
                    return -1;
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a valid soap envelope for this request. In your code, you missed to define a POST request with your curl.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
```

Comment: Above line added in code,still i am facing the same problem.Is there any other cause for this error.